# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, arima

How I can repair this error:
    ### attempt 4
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    user = '*****'
    pasw = '*****'
    host = 'TD'

```
# connect
td_engine = create_engine('teradata://' + user + ':' + pasw + '@' + host + ':22/')
```

> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>
> ## engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True) user = '****' pasw = '****' host = 'TD'
>
> ## connect td_engine = create_engine('teradata://' + user + ':' + pasw + '@' + host + ':22/') Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 8, in 
>       td_engine = create_engine('teradata://' + user + ':' + pasw + '@' + host + ':22/')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine__init__.py",
>   line 387, in create_engine
>       return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py",
>   line 56, in create
>       entrypoint = u._get_entrypoint()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py",
>   line 139, in _get_entrypoint
>       cls = registry.load(name)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users****\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py",
>   line 218, in load
>       (self.group, name))
>
> NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:teradata

Comment: This is a lot of code in a format that isn't easy to replicate. Try making a [mcve]. In particular it needs to be minimal: cut out code until the error almost disappears. And replace the use of an excel file with lists directly in the code.

Comment: Where is variable `mse` comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add frequency in your series data.
y = y.asfreq(freq='7d')

Reference: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.asfreq.html#pandas.Series.asfreq